# pandas : Substract each row from previous, and group result by max

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

I will try to explain the best I can, For each user I have 2 counterq incremented every 15 minutes (Traf1 and Traf2,I count 96 values per day), I need to to calculate 2 new values each 15 minutes for each user by substracting from previous value (15 minutes before) and calculate the max for each user and in the end join with exact time collection for this max (more clear with my excel file).

```
ID  date_collection time_collect_traf1  traf1   time_collect_traf2  traf2
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 00:02    42722552446 06/10/2020 00:02    48354907401
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 00:17    42723408951 06/10/2020 00:17    48355583235
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 00:32    42724472767 06/10/2020 00:32    48356231232
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 00:47    42725824692 06/10/2020 00:47    48356923086
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 01:02    42726780008 06/10/2020 01:02    48357843935
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 01:17    42727942297 06/10/2020 01:17    48358668348
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 01:32    42728814704 06/10/2020 01:32    48359370387
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 01:47    42729720388 06/10/2020 01:47    48360064369
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 02:03    42730648238 06/10/2020 02:03    48360775116
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 02:17    42732118437 06/10/2020 02:17    48361489390
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 02:32    42735743381 06/10/2020 02:32    48362475815
```

Exemple from a file : [Excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rSrN4BNbeuMHjM3EPEE3Law_KY4PeJ36/view?usp=sharing)

How to calculate :

1-for columns traf1,traf2,for each user I need to made substract for each  value from the previous value according to time_collection

2-once the delta calulated, I have to group by max, and for each one I need the time_collection when I reach the max.

For exemple, in my excel file I calculated Delta1 and Delta2, the max I need is in yellow and the time for this max also.

My out from excel file must be somethink like this :

```
ID  date_collection time_collect_traf1  time_collect_traf2  Max_Delta_Traf1 Max_Delta_traf2
USER1   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 22:02    126733343   06/10/2020 10:32    5442197
USER2   06/10/2020  06/10/2020 13:17    1917627204  06/10/2020 15:17    84254498
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The question is somehow veague. You want the record which is maximum between delta1 and delta2 for each user?
In your example you've missed the column delta2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to findout what you need. hope the answer is what you need:

```
df =pd.read_excel('USERS_FILE.xlsx')
df=(
    df
    .assign(diff1 = lambda x: x[['ID','date_collection','traf1']].groupby(['ID','date_collection']).diff())
    .assign(diff2 = lambda x: x[['ID','date_collection','traf2']].groupby(['ID','date_collection']).diff())
)
print(
    df[['ID','time_collect_traf1','diff1']]
    .sort_values('diff1',ascending=False)
    .groupby(['ID'])
    .head(1)
    .merge(
        (
            df[['ID','time_collect_traf2','diff2']]
            .sort_values('diff2',ascending=False)
            .groupby(['ID'])
            .head(1)),
        on='ID',
        how='left'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work, I want an out with one line per user only, calculating the delta first (substract from previous value) and than doing max for each delta

Comment: It returns max for each delta for each user. You have 2 delta so you will have 2 max for each user and it means 4 records. Like records highlighted in your excel. Am I wrong?

Comment: In my excel I have two users, I calculated delta1 and delta2, when I group by max for delta1 and delta 2, I will have one value for delta1 (the max) and anothet max for delta2, so it will give one line by user....then I will try to add time collection for this max by tryng to join with original dataframe

Comment: I fixed the solution according to what you want. please let me know if its not enough

Comment: thank you, it doesn't work, it give me a new df with all line, I need an output just with 2 line, one line for each user..I don't understand all your code, but I fn't see when you group by max after diff...

Comment: I added a print to print the df and if you do this what you get is exactly what you want. I created 2 set one for first diff and one for secend diff and I get the max value for each user and then I merge those dfs.

Comment: ahh thank you, it was my fault, I do a print for all df...